# How to increase the output line length of \errmessage and \typeout

Tags: tex-core

Is there a way to increase the output line length of `\errmessage` and `\typeout`? My problem is that some error messages in my console and log file are cut within the error content:

```
--> Error: This is my very long<LF>
error message.
```

Instead I would like to have:

```
--> Error: This is my very long error message.
```

in one line because I've to parse the log file.

Many thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3):

You can not control this within TeX but web2c based implementations have

```
% It's probably inadvisable to change these. At any rate, we must have:
% 45 < error_line      < 255;
% 30 < half_error_line < error_line - 15;
% 60 <= max_print_line;
% These apply to TeX, Metafont, and MetaPost.
error_line = 79
half_error_line = 50
max_print_line = 79
```

These settings are usually set in a `texmf.cnf` file but you can also set them on the commandline so

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}

\typeout{+123456789+123456789+123456789+123456789+123456789+123456789+123456789+123456789+123456789+123456789}
\end{document}
```

produces

```
$ pdflatex bb076
This is pdfTeX, Version 3.141592653-2.6-1.40.23 (TeX Live 2022/dev) (preloaded format=pdflatex)
 restricted \write18 enabled.
entering extended mode
(./bb076.tex
LaTeX2e <2021-06-01> patch level 1
L3 programming layer <2021-08-27>
(/usr/local/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/article.cls
Document Class: article 2021/02/12 v1.4n Standard LaTeX document class
(/usr/local/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/size10.clo))
(/usr/local/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/latex/l3backend/l3backend-pdftex.def)
(./bb076.aux)
+123456789+123456789+123456789+123456789+123456789+123456789+123456789+12345678
9+123456789+123456789
(./bb076.aux) )
No pages of output.
Transcript written on bb076.log.
```

but

```
$ pdflatex --cnf-line=max_print_line=100 bb076
This is pdfTeX, Version 3.141592653-2.6-1.40.23 (TeX Live 2022/dev) (preloaded format=pdflatex)
 restricted \write18 enabled.
entering extended mode
(./bb076.tex
LaTeX2e <2021-06-01> patch level 1
L3 programming layer <2021-08-27> (/usr/local/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/article.cls
Document Class: article 2021/02/12 v1.4n Standard LaTeX document class
(/usr/local/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/size10.clo))
(/usr/local/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/latex/l3backend/l3backend-pdftex.def) (./bb076.aux)
+123456789+123456789+123456789+123456789+123456789+123456789+123456789+123456789+123456789+123456789

(./bb076.aux) )
No pages of output.
Transcript written on bb076.log.
```

Comment: Thanks so far. I'll try.